# Bug in google doc list item management?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have developped a script to transform paragraphs into list item, using a specific list item model (StyleT1 in the doc).
I have a very strange behavior:
1/ if you select the first paragraph of the doc and launch the script, it works well and the paragraph become a list item copying the format of StyleT1
2/ if you select the second paragraph and apply the script, then all the list item paragraph become with a number instead of a bullet

I think it is clearly a bug: what do you think?

https://docs.google.com/document/d/16i4nzxj0ptIgjaD6pjVedJqi3wwlw-PtN-W-AGOVuoU/edit?usp=sharing

```
function manageStyles() {
try {

var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody();
var elementTable = [];
var paragraphe, ParagrapheIndex, Text;

var selectionRange = doc.getSelection() ? doc.getSelection().getRangeElements() : null;

if (!selectionRange) {
  console.log("No selection!");
  return;
}

var ListT1 = body.findText("StyleT1");    
ListT1 = ListT1.getElement().getParent();    

for (var i=0; i < selectionRange.length; i++){
 elementTable[i] = selectionRange[i].getElement();
 }

for (var i=0; i < elementTable.length; i++){
  if (elementTable[i].getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT) {
    paragraphe = elementTable[i].getParent();     
  } else if (elementTable[i].getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH || elementTable[i].getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
    paragraphe = elementTable[i];
  } else {
    console.log("Not applicable the selection!");
    continue;
  }

Text = paragraphe.getText();
ParagrapheIndex = body.getChildIndex(paragraphe);
body.removeChild(paragraphe);
paragraphe = body.insertListItem(ParagrapheIndex,Text); 
paragraphe.setListId(ListT1);  
/*paragraphe.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
paragraphe.setNestingLevel(0);  */          

  
} // fin du for
} catch (e) {
console.log("Error in manageStyles " + e.toString());
}
}
```

Thx Rman

Comment: Your code works if you remove `paragraphe.setListId(ListT1);`  as well as adding the script ` paragraphe.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
paragraphe.setNestingLevel(0); ` although im not quite sure what is the purpose of `var ListT1 = body.findText("StyleT1");` since everything works fine even without this.

Comment: Hi. My purpose is to use personal glyph and format for my list, based on the model 'StyleT1' in the doc. So the use of setListId instead of Bullet and nesting level that will put a default list format.
So yes it works fine but not at all what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Would be you be able to clarify or provide a sample on what item list model StyleT1 should look like?

Comment: Hi. You have it in the link to the google doc, above, where "StyleT1" is described and used as model

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, what I understood is that you would want to set the current Glyph Type of the string "StyleT1" to any selection range within your document, is that correct?

Comment: If its the case above my previous comment, you might want to consider using [getGlyphType() under Class ListItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item?hl=ja)

Comment: Hi. You can find it in the google doc i have shared, where it is written "StyleT1"

Comment: The issue is that glyph type is very restricted and for example does not allow to set up a "star bullet", like in my example. It is why i'm trying to copy/paste a complete format.

Comment: You can file a bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/) instead